# How to use ModelState.IsValid with complex objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using NHibernate and I've got a `Campaign` class and it has a `Client` class as one of its members and I'm attempting to use `ModelState.IsValid` in my `[HttpPost] public Create (CreateCampaignViewModel vm)` method.

As my ViewModel contains the object `Campaign` `ModelStats.IsValid` is always false as I'm passing the `Client.Id` from the form instead of the entire `Client` object.

Is there a way to have it load the Client member before it runs the validation code that sets `ModelState.IsValid`?  Or is there a way to refresh the state of `ModelState` after I 'manually' retrieve the client object based on the ClientId and bind it to the Campaign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add an attribute to the parameter of your action method, to disable binding of the Id:

```
[HttpPost]
public Create([Bind(Ignore="ClientId")]CreateCampaignViewModel vm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Steven Sanderson has a blog post on just this. He removes any of the items which do not have incoming values from the errors collection.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/02/19/partial-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2/

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the overloads on the controller's UpdateModel method. Then call ModelState.IsValid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SharpArch has a modelbinder that can load the NH objects. But, I don't like that idea very much...instead I'd use a separate PostModel to hold the posted form values. If you re-use the ViewModel to also hold the post data, you'll usually have a lot of fields that make no sense to be posted (like the Client object in your example) or readonly display fields.

```
class CampaignPostModel{
    ...
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

All you need to do is match-up the property names to the form input names and add this as a parameter on your post action method.